# Get the function result from a class

Tags: php, function, class

I have a function inside a class, and I would like to get the result of this function, something like:

> Returned dangerous functions are: dl, system

Here is my code

```
public final function filterFile(){

$disabled_functions = ini_get('disable_functions');

$disFunctionsNoSpace = str_replace(' ', '', $disabled_functions);

$disFunctions = explode(',', $disFunctionsNoSpace);

$this->disFunctions = $disFunctions;

// get file content of the uploaded file (renamed NOT the temporary)
$cFile = file_get_contents($this->fileDestination, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);


$found = array();

foreach($this->disFunctions as $kkeys => $vvals)
{            
    if(preg_match('#'.$vvals.'#i', $cFile))
    {                  
        array_push($found, $vvals);

    } 
} // end foreach

} // end filterFile

// calling the class
$up = new uploadFiles($filename);

$fileterringFile    = $up->filterFile();

print_r($fileterringFile);
var_dump($fileterringFile);
```

EDIT: add 2 functions for errors:

```
// check if any uErrors
public final function checkErrors(){

    $countuErrors = count($this->uErrors);

    if((IsSet($this->uErrors) && (is_array($this->uErrors) && ($countuErrors > 0))))
    {
        return true;            
    }
        return false;
} // end checkErrors()


// print user errors
public final function printErrors(){

    $countuErrors = count($this->uErrors);

    if((IsSet($this->uErrors) && (is_array($this->uErrors) && ($countuErrors > 0))))
    {

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($this->uErrors as $uV)
        {       
            echo '<li>';
            echo $uV;
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }                
} // end printErrors()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

at the end of end filterFile, add:

```
return 'Returned dangerous functions are: '.implode(',',$found);
```

Comment: I am not looking to add it there, I am looking to get them while calling a class

Comment: it will have to be returned by some class method - wont it?

Comment: So I should use another function to get these values and print them?

Comment: well i believe so, to be hones what you want is not clear

Comment: And to check in global, that this function has a dangerous functions then print them, something like: `if($filterringfile) is true then echo $filterError`, filterError will print the errors comes from filterringFile

Comment: what sets `filterError`?

Comment: I added 2 functions to get and print errors, edited above on my code, now I would like to make sure that filterringFile function returned any dangerous item, so I can call the function error to print them